# Searching with fork in C

Tags: c, fork, binary-search

I'm supposed to be getting comfortable with fork, and I saw an exercise that said to use a fork call to search an array indexed from 0 to 15. We're to assume that each process can only do two things...(1) is to check to see if an array is length 1, and (2) compare a single element of an array to the number were searching for. Basically i pass it a number, and its supposed to do a finite number of forks and return the index of that number. Here's my code..

```
#define MAXINDEX 16

int forkSearch(int a[], int search, int start, int end){
  if(start == end){
    if(*(a + end) == search){
      return end;
    }
  } 
  else{
    pid_t child = fork();
    if(child == 0) return forkSearch(a, search, start, end/2);
    else return forkSearch(a, search, (start + end)/2, end);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int searchArray[MAXINDEX] = {1, 12, 11, 5, 10, 6, 4, 9, 13, 2, 8, 14, 3,\
                               15, 7};
  printf("Should be 1. Index of 12 = %d\n", forkSearch(searchArray,
                                                       12, 0, MAXINDEX));
  return 0;
}
```

Everything in the return of this quickly exploding program seems to be either 1, 10, 11, or 13. Why isn't this working like it should.

Comment: not your solution, but did you intend to init that array of 16 int's with 15 values ?

Comment: "I'm supposed to be getting comfortable with fork" - Try the Spoon and be careful with the knife :-)

Comment: Shouldn't your child process be searching `(a, search, start, (start + end) / 2)` rather than `(a, search, start, end/2)`?  The two are only equivalent when start == 0, which won't always be the case...

Comment: @EdHeal lol. ok that was good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(child == 0) return forkSearch(a, search, start, end/2);
```

That's the wrong `end` there, it should be `(start+end)/2`, and the start index of the search in the right half should be `(start+end)/2 + 1`. Otherwise, if the right half is `(start+end)/2 .. end`, when `end == start+1`, the `start` for the recursive call is the old `start` value and you have an infinite loop.

Your programme has undefined behaviour because

```
int forkSearch(int a[], int search, int start, int end){
  if(start == end){
    if(*(a + end) == search){
      return end;
    }
  }
```

doesn't return a value if `start == end`, but `*(a+end) != search`. Add an `exit(0);` after the inner `if` to exit the processes that didn't find the target.

```
int searchArray[MAXINDEX] = {...};

forkSearch(searchArray, 12, 0, MAXINDEX)
```

will lead to an out-of-bounds access at `searchArray[MAXINDEX]`, also undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay, something about shooting fish in a barrel, but I don't get the joke, unfortunately.

Comment: Now it just runs infinitely in a loop..? FIXED. Found it. Did the -1 in the wrong spot..