# Binary search with fork()

Tags: c, fork

I'm trying to create a binary search tree using 2 sons. They will return 1 if the element searched has been found or 0 otherwise.

```
#define m_index 16
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int fork_search(int a[], int search, int start, int end) {
    if (start == end) {
        if (*(a + end) == search) {
            return 1;
        }

       return 0;
    } else{
        pid_t child = fork();
        if (child == 0)
            return fork_search(a, search, start, (start+end)/2);
        else {
            // creating the second son here
            pid_t child2 = fork();
            if (child2 == 0)
                return fork_search(a, search, (start + end)/2+1, end);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a[m_index] = {1, 12, 11, 5, 10, 6, 4, 9, 13, 2, 8, 14, 3, 15, 7};

    printf("%d\n", fork_search(a, 12, 0, m_index-1));

    return 0;
}
```

How can I create a second son to search the upper half? If it's the father I could simply write `return fork_search(a, search, (start + end)/2+1, end);`, however, I need the second son to do this. Thank you!

Comment: you have confused between binary search and binary search tree..!!

Comment: After forking, you have to relay the status by `exit()` with status 0 or 1, with the parent waiting (`wait()` or `waitpid()`) for the child processes and reporting back the composite status from the children. Also, this looks like it will always search everything, rather than eliminating half the search range all the time.  You'd have to wait for the first child to finish, and only if it reports failure would you launch the second child.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876366/searching-with-fork-in-c.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about how `fork()` works. Also about how binary searches work.

### Using fork() to traverse a tree

`fork()` merely starts a copy of the current process (technically a copy-on-write copy). So it will return success provided the fork succeeds.

In fact, it returns *twice* on success, once to the child, and once to the parent. From the man page:

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and
>   0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the  parent,
>   no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

So, first you need to check the `fork()` did not fail (did not return -1). If it did, you abort your search.

If the `fork()` returned 0, you are the child, so you can search one limb of your tree. Otherwise you are the parent, in which case you need to do the second `fork()`, then `wait()` for both children to complete. And pass the results back with `exit()` (`return` will merely lead to each child printing the line to `stdout` in `main()`).

Note that this way of traversing a binary tree will produce one process for every node in the tree (or every node in the tree with children). This may in effect be a fork bomb, i.e. you may DoS your own computer. You may therefore want to limit the levels of `fork()` used (i.e. switch to a conventional search when you are more than `n` levels deep).

### Confusion between a binary search and traversing a tree

The second issue here is that the whole point of a binary search (as opposed to a tree) is that you examine the item half way along the search range, then only search to *one* side of it, i.e. you do not need to process both sides. This eliminates the need for `fork()`.

Here the contents of the array that you are searching are not in order, so you aren't doing a binary search. You are (in effect) traversing a tree, where the root node is half way along, the next nodes up are half way between the ends and the root nodes, etc.